# HP Quality Center

Tags: jenkins, build, automation, hp-quality-center

I am investigating a way to automate some of our build processes using Jenkins and HPQC. Currently, we have a process where, once a change to fix a defect has been checked in we set its status to "Fixed" and then reassign defect in HPQC from the individual developers to a team lead.

The team lead is tasked with manually deploying a build for the deliverable to the test environment and when he does this he will then update all of the defects assigned to him this way reassigning them to the test lead, who can assign them to individual testers.

I would like to automate this process where I can. Does HPQC have a web API of some kind? So that a remote system (such as a Jenkins build server) could run a post-build action script to gather a bunch of defect numbers (those included in the build) find each defect in HPQC and then update its status and owner?

Answer (score 1):

There is a REST API for ALM / Quality Center, info is accessible:

http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/manuals

You will have to sign up for an account with HP to access it.  Ugh, troglodytes.

Search for "ALM REST API", download and read the newest guide and reference for your version of QC.

(We also use QC at my work.  It's pretty damn bad.  I should try and convince them to get or build something better.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is a good one, I found the reference he mentions, but making use of that is not very intuitive, probably because I am such a newb. For my fellow unenlightened you might want to use another reference I found for how to use the reference :
http://www.consulting-bolte.de/index.php/22-hp-alm/hp-alm-rest-api/115-connect-to-hp-alm-via-java-using-rest-api

The key piece of information for me was that inside all of these class files they give you in the "Example Applications" folder there is a reference to a package :

package org.hp.qc.web.restapi.docexamples.docexamples.infrastructure;

This is just another name for all the files located in the guide in the "infrastructure" subfolder. You do not need to go find this out on github or something.